# Can I run Apache Flink within an Android App?

Tags: android, apache-flink

I was trying to run Apache Flink within an Android App. I just want to run a minimum working example, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    runFlinkExample();
}

private void runFlinkExample() {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStream<Integer> stream = env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    stream.print();
    try {
        env.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These are my two .gradle files:

build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flink"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'reference.conf'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Flink
    implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.12:1.12.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.12:1.12.1'
}
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The first problem is, that I get the following Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~DbT_CZ7AhLED2xZgLBk ....
```

In cases there this error doesn't appear, I get Akka-Actor errors, because I must exclude 'reference.conf', otherwise the code wouldn't compile. However, this leads to more exceptions, e.g. missing akka-version.

So my general question is: Is it possible to run Flink within an Android-App? Or is this not possible (recommended)? Perhaps someone knows how to modfiy my gradle files (or something else) to run my example. Or perhaps someone already has successfully used Flink in Android.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume vanilla Flink will not run on Android. It's using some direct buffers, reflections, and Unsafe methods, which do not run on Android afaik.

Could you explain your use case, so that I can get an idea how much value there is in getting Flink running on Android for you?

---

Edit: Extending for comment

Flink is primarily a tool for distributed data processing. It can be used on a single machine, but the usual assumption is that it's powerful enough to scale up. I don't see a single Android phone as a viable hardware for that purpose.

I think you just want to use the CEP DSL for local event processing. You probably don't need any parallelism at all. In that case, I'd look for a simple CEP framework, such as [Esper](http://esper.sourceforge.net/esper-0.7.5/doc/reference/en/html/event_patterns.html). If it's running non-distributed, it can offer even more functionality than Flink.

Comment: I want to use FlinkCEP for detecting patterns in Android Sensor values in real-time. The data-stream would be generated by the sensors (gyroscope and accerlerometer). Then I want to detect patterns, e.g: gyroX-value > 0.2 followedBy accY-value < 0.001 followedBy ...
So I was hoping that there is a way to run FlinkCEP on Android.

Comment: Extended my message to address your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I just need the CEP-DSL. But for CEP I need to setup a local stream execution environment like in Vanilla Flink. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: Like I said, I'd look for a non-flink solution in your case. You are trying to install a screw with a hammer.